# Have div width match that of the contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, handsontable

I have a container div that holds a react handsontable component, and I want to use the autosizing of the component but at the same time have it centered in the screen (or an outer div).

So in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/opike99/b1ux0rLy/5/

I'm trying to get the width of div #example1 to match the contents of the table (so by changing the number of columns, the div width will adjust accordingly).

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@11.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@11.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" /> 
<script src="https://handsontable.com/docs/8.3.2/components/numbro/dist/languages.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer2">
<div class="outer1">
  <div id="example1">



  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#example1');

const numberOfColumns = 7;

const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5, numberOfColumns),
  colHeaders: true,
  rowHeaders: true,
  hiddenColumns: true,
  width: 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
});


// re-render your Handsontable instance
hot.render()
```

CSS:

```
.outer2 {
}

.outer1 {
}

#example1 {
    border-style: solid;
    /* width: fit-content; */
}
```

Comment: `margin: auto`?

Comment: margin: auto works after setting a fixed width. Will margin: auto work with a dynamic width of the div's contents?

Comment: Misunderstood you, sorry. Gimme 5

Comment: Maybe setting the outer div's CSS like `{ display: flex; justify-content: center; }` would do it? (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).)

Comment: Tried that. Sets width to 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been playing around with your example, and got the following results:

There's actually three tings you need to do:

1. The generated `$('.wtHolder')` has a `width: 680px` defined on a style attribute, so the only way to remove it is programatically.
2. `$('.ht_master.handsontable, #example1')` need `width: fit-content`
3. Using a flexbox, I was able to centre the table. I set `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on `$('.outer1')`.

And for some reason, the order in which these are applied is important too. I got it working with a `setTimeout`, although you'd probably want something more sophisticated.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.wtHolder').style.width = 'initial';
  document.querySelector('#example1').style.width = 'fit-content';
  const outer = document.querySelector('.outer1');
  outer.style.display = 'flex';
  outer.style.justifyContent = 'center';
}, 2000);
```

Let me know how you go.